# Brightcove HTML5 style customize

Tags: javascript, brightcove

What should I use to customize HTML5 video player(add own buttons, add css styles)? Now we use javascript plug-ins, but sometimes these pulg-ins are loaded before Iframe DOM. Can you provide us an event which can be used to determine that DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in many places.

**In HTML:**

```
<body onload="alert('DOM loaded!')">
```

**In JavaScript:**

```
window.onload=function(){

   alert("DOM loaded!")
};
```

**In jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("DOM loaded!")
});

// or

$(function() {
   alert("DOM loaded!")
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But in Brightcove player content loaded in iframe from another server, and they create available to add javascript plugins. So I can't use the first option and another not working, they can start before iframe loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want the templateReadyHandler - see http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/player-error-handling

Comment: ok I understand, but how I can to get dom element from this function, course this function is not in iframe element and it has no acsses to content in iframe. I need to create own style of html5 player with responsive design. And I found only one way to do that is's add js plugins, what can change iframe dom, maybe you can advise different way?